# How can I check if a username is taken, while typing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

Many popular websites have a username field that, usually, turns red or blue as a user types in a new character, based on whether or not the characters entered correspond to an already-existing user.

Say I have the following username field:

```
<%= f.text_field :username, id:"username" %>
```

How could that functionality be added to this field?

Comment: You will have to make ajax call when the user is tying

Answer (score 4):

Instead of checking the username and making request on every key, you can use the **`blur`** method to check the user name once the user leaves the username field, or else you need it on every key you can use **`keyup`** itself,

Your Javascript,

```
$( "#username" ).keyup(function() {   # you can also try,  $( "#username" ).blur(function() {
     $.ajax({
        url: '<%= check_duplicate_username_path %>', # your own route
        type: "GET",
        data: { username: $('#username').val() }, // This goes to Controller in params hash, i.e. params[:username]
        complete: function() {},
        success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                   // do something with your returned data //
                   if (data.available == false)
                   {
                    $('#username').addClass("error");   // style the class with your required css
                   }
                 },
        error: function() {
            alert("Your Ajax error! message")
       }
     });
});
```

The route can be taken as,

```
 get '/check_duplicate_username' => 'users#check_duplicate_username', as: :check_duplicate_username
```

The controller action can be something like,

```
 def check_duplicate_username
      @user = User.where('username = ?',params[:username]).first
      if @user.present?
        render json: {:success => 0, :message => 'User exists', :user_available => true}
      else  
        render json: {:success => 1, :message => 'User Does not exist', :user_available => false}
      end   
 end
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to fire `ajax` request on `textbox` event.
write `ajax` function and add new function to you `user_controller` with `GET` http method and return suitable response for check availabilty of your username.

Answer (score 2):

Trigger an ajax request while writing on the text box. Like:

```
$( "#username" ).keyup(function() {
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '<%= username_availability_path %>', # replace by your route
        data: {name: $('#username').prop('value')}
     });
});
```

Create a `new` route on your `routes.rb` file with type `GET`. In the method access the typed name using `params[:name]` and then check if exists or not. Then do whatever you want.